# Java: alternative to global variables to pass values from methods to another

Tags: java, methods, parameter-passing

Just out of curiosity! If I got a method that takes user input and stores it as an int variable. Is there a way I could pass those methods on to another method? I know about return values, but that is only (as far as I know) for one single number,object etc...

The easy way would of course to just to do calculate the result within this method, but is it possible somehow to pass these ints: a,b. To another method, without using global variables? I am just wondering.

```
private void takeInput(int valueA, int valueB){
    println("Enter a number: (a) and (b), to calculate the Phytagoeran Theorem: (c)\n");
    int a = readInt("a:");
    println("you set the value of a to: "+a +"\n\nNext! set the value of b");
    int b = readInt("b:");
    println("you set the value of b to:"+b);
}
```

Comment: A little confused between what you stated in your first paragraph and second. So, you want to pass values of `variables` from one method to another?

Comment: This is not really an OOP way to do it. You should create an object which holds any information that is needed and pass that around.

Comment: Having written a response to your question "Is there a way I could pass those methods on to another method?", I now wonder if that's what you mean? Should it be "Is there a way I could pass those *values* on to another method"?

Comment: @slim: yep, that was initially what I meant, but got a interesting answer on how to pass methods on to another method... I already knew this from Obj-C. But programming in JAVA thought still object-oriented. Sometimes just don´t think so clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is unclear, but I wonder whether you've invented "dependency injection"?

The first part of the puzzle is that, yes, a method can return more than one value, by wrapping them in an object.

```
public class ValuePair {
    public int a;
    public int b;
}

public ValuePair takeInput(){
  ValuePair pair = new ValuePair();
  println("Enter a number: (a) and (b)\n");
  pair.a = readInt("a:");
  pair.b = readInt("b:");
  return pair;
}
```

And with that you can do:

```
ValuePair p = takeInput();
System.out.println("Hypotenuse is " + calculateHypotenuse(p.a, p.b) + "\n";
```

(Note that public fields are not usually considered good style - I use them here because the code is shorter. In real code use getters and setters).

---

That might be all the answer you need. But you ask:

> Is there a way I could pass those methods on to another method?

Well, yes you can if you wrap that method in a class dedicated the purpose. For reasons that I hope will become apparent, we'll define an interface first.

```
 public interface ValuePairSource {
    public ValuePair getPair();
}
```

... and a class that implements it:

```
public class UserInputValuePairSource implements ValuePairSource {
    @Override
    public ValuePair getPair() {
         ValuePair pair = new ValuePair();
         println("Enter a number: (a) and (b)\n");
         pair.a = readInt("a:");
         pair.b = readInt("b:");
         return pair;
    }
}
```

Now you could create a Pythagoras class that can be told where to get its values.

```
public class Pythagoras {
     private ValuePairSource valuePairSource;

     public Pythagoras(ValuePairSource source) {
         this.valuePairSource = source;
     }

     public double hypotenuse() {
         ValuePair pair = valuePairSource.getPair();
         return Math.sqrt(pair.a ^ 2 + pair.b ^ 2)
     }
}
```

In the constructor, we tell each Pythagoras object we create, how to get a pair of values. So we can use it like this:

```
Pythagoras p = new Pythagoras(new UserInputValuePairSource());
double hypotenuse = p.hypotenuse();
```

What use is this? Well, it means we can invent other kinds of ValuePairSource. For example, a ShapeValuePairSource, which gets the values from a Shape object we set it up with.

(These are hypothetical classes for the purpose of the question)

So you might use it like this:

```
Triangle t = canvas.getLastTriangle(); // or whatever
ValuePairSource vps = new ShapeValuePairSource(triangle);
Pythagoras p = new Pythagoras(vps);
double hypotenuse = p.hypotenuse();
```

So without changing the Pythagoras class at all, we now have it reading the values from a shape object, rather than user input.

OK, it's a bit of a contrived example, but it does answer the question "could I pass those methods to another method" -- and this is the basis of things like Spring.

Note that some languages allow you to pass methods directly to other methods, without wrapping them in a class as we have here. This is called "functional programming", and usually the "methods" are called "functions".

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that holds the 2 values:

```
public class PairOfInt {
    private final int a, b;

    public PairOfInt(int a, int b) {
       this.a = a;
       this.b = b;
    }

    //getters
}


private PairOfInt takeInput(){
    println("Enter a number: (a) and (b), to calculate the Phytagoeran Theorem: (c)\n");
    int a = readInt("a:");
    println("you set the value of a to: "+a +"\n\nNext! set the value of b");
    int b = readInt("b:");
    println("you set the value of b to:"+b);
    return new PairOfInt(a, b);
}
```

Comment: This would be like creating a getter & setter method for the variable? then accessing it´s getter to get the value of the variable from within other methods?

Comment: Yes that's the idea (just a getter in my example)

Answer (score 0):

You can declare another method like this:

```
private void doSomething(int a, int b) {
  ...
}
```

Then, from your method `takeInput`, you can call it:

```
doSomething(a, b);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a class with all the members which you want to operate upon and create methods in the same class that way you need not to pass the variables across methods and you don't need to rely on global variables.

```
class MyOperations {

    private int valueA;
    private int valueB;

    public MyOperations (int valueA, int valueB) {
      this.valueA = valueA;
      this.valueB = valueB;
    }

    public void doOperationA(){
    //
    }

    public void doOperationB(){
    //
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoiding global variables is usually a good idea.

There are two main ways of passing multiple return values:

1. Returning the values in a composite object
2. Putting the values into an object passed as a parameter

**The first way** involves returning an object that contains all the values you want to return. You could use a class that's already available, like a Map or a List:

```
public List readIntegersFromInput() {
      List l = new ArrayList();
      l.add(readInt("a: "));
      l.add(readInt("b: "));
      return l;
}
```

... or you could create a class especially for your needs:

```
public class ValuesAandB {
    public int a;
    public int b;
}
```

... to be used like this:

```
public ValuesAandB readIntegersFromInput() {
      ValuesAandB ab = new ValuesAandB;
      ab.a = readInt("a: ");
      ab.b = (readInt("b: ");
      return ab;
}
```

(in real code, use setters and getters instead of public fields)

**The second way** involves passing an *mutable* object as a parameter. A mutable object is an object whose values can be changed -- like the ValuesAandB class we have just created.

```
public void readIntegersFromInput(ValuesAandB ab) {
    ab.a = readInt("a: ");
    ab.b = (readInt("b: ");
}
```

... which you would call like this:

```
ValuesAandB values = new ValuesAandB();
readIntegersFromInput(values);
// use `values`
```

**So which is best?** You will see both styles in production code. It's generally agreed nowadays that in most cases, the first style is preferable.

It's actually a good idea to make classes which are *immutable*, that is a ValuesAandB in which you set the values in the constructor, then never allow them to be changed. If you need different values, then you have to create a new object. You can see that with immutable objects, the second way can't be done. It leads to cleaner code that's easier to understand.